# How to prepare attendance sheet in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, database-design

I want to add a attendance sheet for HR record purpose, where they save attendance of different employees. Then I have to retrieve those records on different pages on searching respective fields.

Comment: Can you specify, how you intend to do it, what you have tried and what is not working ?

Comment: I have tried it with gridview to edit records...but m not getting what fields i should have in database..Like i have emp name,emp id....I mean I have keep to record of all employees attendance..how can i do it?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a `gridview` to accomplish your task you can use the `SQLDataSource` control which will allow you to perform different commands like `insert`, `edit` and `update`.

Here you can use [GridView.DataBind](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fkx0cy6d.aspx) Method to bind data to your `gridview`.

The article about [Simple Insert, Select, Edit, Update and Delete in Asp.Net GridView control](http://www.aspdotnetcodes.com/GridView_Insert_Edit_Update_Delete.aspx) will give you a better idea of doing

Comment: I have started doing it with gridview...but i have a problem how to save records with of different months..

Comment: saving the records should be deal with tha database. you can use gridview to populate records by month or year

Answer (score 0):

This is rather a database design question then asp.net. Starting from a simple design, first you need to have an Employee table (Call it Employees) with all employee names & secondly an attendance table which will record each employee attendance. Refer to my sample schema [image]